# Error while running a webapp from a JAR

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t-java, sites-9.1

We are upgrading a DD4T java webapp. DD4T 2.1.5 with adoptopenjdk 11.0.6_10 is being used.

In the process of upgrading the CD dependencies from 8.5 to 9.1 an exception pops up during a request.

Note that this happens only when the webapp is packed into a JAR(using Spring Boot). When running the app unpacked from the filesystem everyting is working fine.

```
13:28:22.485 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG c.t.s.c.StorageConfigurationTransformer - Provider schema jar of input URL jar:file:/D:/myapp/target/myapp-2.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/cd_storage_conf.xml 
13:28:22.490 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'StorageManagerImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/myapp/target/myapp-2.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/udp-datalayer-11.1.0-1060.jar!/com/tridion/storage/management/StorageManagerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configurationLoader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageResourceConfigurationLoaderImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException 
13:28:22.498 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.t.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent - Fatal error, unable to load the DynamicContent Module 13:28:22.498 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.t.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent - Fatal error, unable to load the DynamicContent Module 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'StorageManagerImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Repos/myapp/target/myapp-2.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/udp-datalayer-11.1.0-1060.jar!/com/tridion/storage/management/StorageManagerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configurationLoader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageResourceConfigurationLoaderImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.SpringContentDeliveryKernel.ensureInitialised(SpringContentDeliveryKernel.java:38) ~[udp-core-11.1.0-1043.jar!/:11.1.0-1043]
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.registerKernel(KernelFactory.java:40) ~[udp-core-11.1.0-1043.jar!/:11.1.0-1043]
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.getKernel(KernelFactory.java:27) ~[udp-core-11.1.0-1043.jar!/:11.1.0-1043]
    at com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationRepositoryRegister.register(ConfigurationRepositoryRegister.java:29) ~[udp-discovery-11.1.0-1056.jar!/:11.1.0-1050]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.<init>(DynamicContent.java:126) ~[udp-api-dynamic-11.1.0-1054.jar!/:11.1.0-1054]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.getInstance(DynamicContent.java:89) ~[udp-api-dynamic-11.1.0-1054.jar!/:11.1.0-1054]
    at org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerPublicationProvider.discoverPublicationByBaseUrl(BrokerPublicationProvider.java:52) ~[dd4t-providers-2.1.5-DXA.jar!/:na]
    at myapp.CachingPublicationProvider.discoverPublicationByBaseUrl(CachingPublicationProvider.java:35) ~[classes!/:2.0.0]
    at myapp.TridionContentService.getContentPage(TridionContentService.java:87) ~[classes!/:2.0.0]
    at myapp.controller.PageController.getPage(PageController.java:101) ~[classes!/:2.0.0]
-- REMOVED FOR BREVITY --
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:169) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:155) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:208) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:97) ~[na:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageConfigurationTransformer.doTransformConfiguration(StorageConfigurationTransformer.java:88) ~[udp-datalayer-11.1.0-1060.jar!/:11.1.0-1060]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageConfigurationTransformer.transformConfiguration(StorageConfigurationTransformer.java:60) ~[udp-datalayer-11.1.0-1060.jar!/:11.1.0-1060]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageResourceConfigurationLoaderImpl.init(StorageResourceConfigurationLoaderImpl.java:33) ~[udp-datalayer-11.1.0-1060.jar!/:11.1.0-1060]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 117 common frames omitted
```

Has anyone ran into this issue?

Comment: Are you using the in-process CD api or the CIL?

Comment: In-process is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question; SDL delivered a hotfix and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Please add the hotfix number to your answer.

Comment: There was no specific hotfix number, they just provided a new JAR. I assume it will be released in the near future.